# Highest man-made voltage

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

What was the [highest voltage](http://www.google.com/search?q=highest+man+made+voltage) achieved and was it produced by electrostatic means or just some transformers and multipliers?
What are the limitations when it comes to producing voltage using electrostatic means?

Comment: Hi Abdel, You mean - artificially? For lightning (Indeed, its electrostatic) - we don't need transformers, etc... :-)

Comment: Yes i mean artificially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a macroscopic potential difference, the largest I know about was in the Nuclear Structure Facility accelerator at the Daresbury laboratory in the UK, and this was 30MV. The Wikipedia article on [electrostatic particle accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator#Electrostatic_particle_accelerators) claims this is about the highest possible in such devices.

Comment: Well I've once heard that  321.5 megavolts was produced in 1979 by the National Electrostatics Corporation

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEsmat - I can't find the reference, but I'm sure this was a typo. It was the Pelletron accelerator and the voltage was 32 $\pm$ 1.5 MV. It got transcribed to 321.5MV.

Comment: What about the EMP in an atomic explosion?  Everything I can look up in the time I have available is on the size of the electric field or the energy of the photons, so I don't know if voltages have been measured, but you would expect something relatively large.

Comment: There must be lots of ways to develop transient very high field strengths. I bet the Z-pinch kit is the US (I forget the name) generates extraordinarily high electric field strengths. However I don't think this in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 7):

Naturally, we already have [Lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) which goes to [some 120 MV](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/1998/MathieuLo.shtml).

A [Van de Graaff Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) produces some $10^7$ volts provided a supply of only $10^4$ volts. It's the [highest man-made voltage ever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28voltage%29) produced.

Some high voltages produced through sparks in this [article](http://teslamania.delete.org/frames/longarc.htm).

Answer (score 1):

In the early 1960's Ferranti Ltd.of Hollinwood Oldham, manufactured a 1.5 Mv 3Mva AC unit comprising two 750kv transformers connected in cascade. 
They also manufactured a 5.2 Mv impulse generator.